# Any way to embed sounds?

Tags: support, feature-request

I would like to embed a sound (a bird song) for a question, but I could see how other people might want to embed sounds for other biological questions.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Related: [Music stackexchange Meta post](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245/youtube-and-soundcloud-embedding-is-now-enabled/246)

Answer (score 4):

There is no such feature. You can upload the file somewhere and share the link.

Comment: The problem with that is that I would have to find a place to host the sound.

Comment: @ImprisonedRhesus Google drive? But there are other free and open sites as well.

Comment: @WYSIWYG But what would be markdown commands for properly "Embed"? (not just hyperlink)

Answer (score 0):

[Music stackexchange](https://music.stackexchange.com) already uses a plug-in for exactly this purpose. It won't be very hard to add one for bio site.

[This](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245/youtube-and-soundcloud-embedding-is-now-enabled) is the discussion on their [meta](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com), and the discussion cites [examples-1](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2720/how-important-is-it-to-have-an-eq-pedal-in-your-chain) (audio-only) and [2](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3243/how-do-i-play-this-tab-of-no-more-sorrows-live-version) (audio with video)

However an "include" or "require" function could be used to specify whether the user want to use the plug-in.